# How to wait for an input validation to complete using HTMX sync?

Tags: htmx

I have an input field (ex: Sort By parameter for a table) and a submit button in a different section of the page (not under the same form element). The input field has a `hx-get` request for validation which is triggered on change.

The problem I'm having is that if someone selects a value in the input field and directly clicks the submit button, both the validation call and the submit call are triggered simultaneously.

I want the validation request to be complete before the submit call is made. From the htmx documentation I think the `hx-sync` functionality is what I need. However, I could not get the submit call to wait for the input call to finish.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.8.4/dist/htmx.min.js"></script>

<div id="table-section">
  <input 
    id="title" 
    name="title" 
    type="text" 
    hx-get="https://httpbin.org/delay/5" 
    hx-trigger="change"
    hx-sync="#submit-button:queue first"
  >
</div>

<br>

<div id="filter-section">
  <button
    id="submit-button"
    hx-include="[name='title']"
    hx-post="https://httpbin.org/post" 
    hx-trigger="click"
    type="submit"
  >
    Submit
  </button>
</div>
```

How do I get the submit to trigger after the input validation is complete?

Comment: Just FYI, I tried your example code and it worked perfectly fine, the submit request was fired only after first search completed, so seems like you code is fine..

Comment: You're right, the submit request is fired after the first search is completed. I should have mentioned that the result of the first search updates the `value` attribute of the input field. The problem I'm facing is that the submit button submits the old value of the input field, not the value returned after validation.